# Random Primary Key missing in SQL Server selection

Tags: sql-server

I am facing a problem when I query master table (**having ~700 Million records and high transactional table**) to look for newly inserted records. My aim is to get all the newly created IDs from the #IDs temp table (Min and Max records) and dump it in another child table. But random IDs are missing in the child table.

**Setup**:

We have a primary and secondary server (SQL Server 2016) and they are in sync mode.

**Tables**:

```
CREATE TABLE tblMaster 
(
    ID BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    EmployeeID INT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE tblChild 
(
    ChildID IDENTITY(1,1), 
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    TransactionDate Datetime NOT NULL
)
```

`tblChild.ID` references `tblMaster.ID`.

Stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @MaxID BIGINT
SELECT @MaxID = MAX(ID) FROM tblChild WITH(NOLOCK)
SET @MaxID = ISNULL(@MaxID, 0)

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #IDS

SELECT ID 
INTO #IDS
FROM tblMaster WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE ID > @MaxID

--25k RECORDS BATCH INSERT INTO tblChild - MAINLY TAKE CARE NEWLY inserted records
STARTIDS:
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #IDS)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TOPIDS
    SELECT TOP 25000 ID INTO #TOPIDS
    FROM #IDS
    ORDER BY ID ASC
    
    INSERT INTO tblChild (ID, CreatedBy, CreatedDate)
        SELECT ID, SYSTEM_USER, GETDATE()
        FROM #TOPIDS
    
    DELETE AA 
    FROM #IDS AA 
    INNER JOIN #TOPIDS BB ON AA.ID = BB.ID

    GOTO STARTIDS
END
```

Please help where it's going wrong.

Comment: Perhaps because you splatter your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) without understanding the consequences.

Comment: Why get the max ID in a separated transaction and statement to getting rows with a greater value to it too? The value could have easily changed between the 2 statements.

Comment: I dont see any issues because I am looking for all the rows greater than Max(ID) from the child table. My expectation is that it will give me all the records between Max and Min ID in temp table #IDS

Comment: Repeat after me: `NOLOCK` may cause [all types of anomalies](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6072/sql-server-nolock-anomalies-issues-and-inconsistencies/), including missed rows, double counting rows, partially committed rows, rows that will never be committed. If that's what you've asked for, that's what you'll get

Comment: Hi Charlie - Thanks for your comment. Just tried by removing the NOLOCK hint and still facing the same issue.